# How to send big image from wp7 to wcf?

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to send an image to wcf to use OCR.
For now, I succeeded in transforming my image into a byte[] and sending it to the server using wcf. Unfortunately, it works for an array whose size is <16Kb and doesn't work for an array >17Kb.

I've already set the `readerQuotas` and `maxArrayLength` to its maximum size in web.config on the server size.

Do you know how to send big data to a wcf server, or maybe any library to use OCR directly on wp7?

Comment: I just found that in the file "configuration91.svcinfo" wich contain the parameters of the wcf in wp7 (need to show hidden files to see it in service references), have :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly solved.
You have to update your web.config to allow the server to receive big data. And then you have to use the Stream type in your WCF and byte[] type in your WP7. Types will match and both WCF or WP7 will agree to receive and send it.

In WCF :

```
public string ConvertImgToStringPiece(Stream img)
{
     //.....
}
```

In WP7 :

```
Service1Client proxy = new Service1Client();    
proxy.ConvertImgToStringPieceCompleted += new EventHandler<ConvertImgToStringPieceCompletedEventArgs>(proxy_ConvertImgToStringPieceCompleted);    
proxy.ConvertImgToStringPieceAsync(b); //b is my Byte[], more thant 17Kb.
```

Answer (score 4):

If all else fails, send it in fragments of 16Kb, followed by an "all done" message that commits it (reassembling if necessary)

Comment: You can't do that because of the Asynchronous function.

Comment: @Bidi that is irrelevant; *yes* you might need to handle multiple callbacks, but that is the implementation - the fundamental "send a number of small requests" is unchanged. I'm no stranger to async; I just don't see *any* reason that it changes anything...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works on WP7, but with WCF you can also use streams to upload bigger amounts of data.

Comment: I've tried to use stream already, but i failed using it. I'll give it another try.

Comment: But if you have others idea or solution, i'll gladly take it.

Comment: Ho my, another problem appeared. When i change the function or its args in wcf i try to update it in wp7 but it doesn't work. When i want to use a stream or a string as arg, it only says it wants a byte[]. Even deleting it and adding the resource again, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a hack but howabout sending it with a HTTP post if it isn't too big? or alternatively changing the webservice so it accepts a blob? (the current array limitation is a limit on the array datatype in the W3C spec)

Comment: Ok i'll give it a try. But i find it strange not to be able to do it directly with their library.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a WCF session. The key thing to remember is that sessions in WCF are different than normal sessions we use for Internet programming. It's basically a call to a method that starts the session, any interim calls, and then a final one that ends the session. You could have a service call that starts the session, send chunks of the image, and then call the last one which closes the session and will return whatever you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx